# Getting all list of item to be displayed at paypal checkout (PHP)

Tags: php, paypal

I tried to display all items at paypal checkout but it only display the last item in the list. For example I have these list in my own cart :

**Item Name**     **Price**

1. Item1   300 USD
2. Item2   200 USD

But when displayed in paypal checkout, only **item2** with it's information will be shown. Refer code below :

**cart-checkout.php**

```
<form class="paypal" action="paypal/payments.php" method="post" id="paypal_form" target="_blank">
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION["username"]))
    {
        $userID = $_SESSION["userid"];
        $sql="SQL query";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
                ?>
                <tr style="background-color: #fff;">
                    <td>
                    <?php 
                        echo $row['productName']; 
                        $productName = $row['productName'];
                        $_SESSION['productName'] = $productName;
                    ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <?php 
                        echo $row['productCode']; 
                        $productCode = $row['productCode'];
                        $_SESSION['productCode'] = $productCode;
                    ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    USD<?php
                        echo $row['price']; 
                        $price = $row['price']; 
                        $_SESSION['$price'] = $price; 
                    ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <?php 
                        echo $row['productQty']; 
                        $productQty = $row['productQty']; 
                        $_SESSION['$productQty'] = $productQty; 
                    ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    USD<?php
                        echo $row['priceTotal']; 
                        $priceTotal = $row['priceTotal']; 
                        $_SESSION['$priceTotal'] = $priceTotal; 
                    ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
                <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="UK" />
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
                <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Payment"/>
</form>
```

**paypal/payments.php**

```
<?php
// some statement for $paypal_email setting
$item_name = $_SESSION['productName'];
$item_amount = $_SESSION['$price'];
$item_number = $_SESSION['productCode'];
$quantity = $_SESSION['$productQty'];

if (!isset($_POST["txn_id"]) && !isset($_POST["txn_type"])){
    $querystring = '';

    $querystring .= "?business=".urlencode($paypal_email)."&";

    $querystring .= "item_name=".urlencode($item_name)."&";
    $querystring .= "amount=".urlencode($item_amount)."&";
    $querystring .= "item_number=".urlencode($item_number)."&";
    $querystring .= "quantity=".urlencode($quantity)."&";

    //loop for posted values and append to querystring
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $querystring .= "$key=$value&";
    }

    // Append paypal return addresses
    $querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
    $querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";
    $querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url);

    header('location:https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring);
    exit();
}
?>
```

**Reference Paypal Integration that I referred to**
http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration

Comment: Where is the code that is displaying the list of items. It's not clear to me which part if your code is running first

Comment: @AndyC check my updated question

Comment: Thanks. So the problem is that in each iteration of your display loop you overwrite your session values, so they end up with the last one.

Comment: You should put those values in to form fields so they can be pulled out to send to PayPal, and they don't need to go in the session

Comment: @AndyC thank you for your good information. I am trying to solve it first with your information. Will update back